# How to extract the id from the object payload?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

For the articlesFetched action I'm getting an array payload like below, how can I extract/assign the id that is coming from the payload into the ids state field and for the state.data assign the whole object?

```
const payload = 
[
 { id: 1,
   items: 4
   color: ['green', 'blue']
 },
 { id: 2,
   items: 10
   color: ['yellow', 'red']
 }
]

export const articlesSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'articles',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        startFetching: (state) => {
            state.loading = true
        },
        articlesFetched: (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false
            state.ids = ??
            state.data = ??
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading things correctly, you should be able to do something like:

```js
export const articlesSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'articles',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        startFetching: (state) => {
            state.loading = true
        },
        articlesFetched: (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false
            state.ids = action.payload.reduce((acc, item) => {
              return [...acc, item.id]
            }, [])
            state.data = action.payload.reduce((acc, item) => {
              return [...acc, ...item.color]
            }, [])
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you're not correctly updating the state, you should not assign the values to the current state because you need to return a new copy of the updated state without mutating the original, you can accomplish what you want using a map function like this.

```
export const articlesSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'articles',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        startFetching: (state) => {
            return {
             ...state,
             loading: true,
            }
        },
        articlesFetched: (state, action) => {
            // Array with the ids
            const ids = action.payload.map(({id}) => id)
            // The whole array with the objects
            const data = action.payload
            return {
              ...state,
              loading: false,
              ids,
              data,
            }
        },
    },
});
```